# Why does the principal suspect these two characters of dealing drugs?

Tags: plot-explanation, sex-education

(This pertains to the Netflix series ***Sex Education***, season 1 episodes 7 and 8.)

At the ball, after principal Groff is harassed by his son Adam, he picks up a jacket and drugs fall on the floor. He picks them up, then the next day he automatically assumes Maeve and Otis are dealing drugs at the school. I've rewatched the scenes at the ball and in the principal's office the next day, but how does the principal go from "random jacket with drugs in" to "I'm sure Maeve and Otis are selling drugs at the school"?

Helper questions to illustrate my point: Whose jacket was it? Why did the principal pick it up? Where did the drugs come from? Are we to assume that after the Percocet he gave to the shy kid, Sean started handing out performance drugs at a ball?  What am I missing?

Comment: Because Maeve's brother was involved in the drug trade? IIRC he suspects the two of them of doing something shady, and then this happens.